# password protect sqlite3 database in php and access it

Tags: php, database, security, sqlite

I am working on an application that will run on local machine, not any web server, which means user can copy paste the database file directly.

I have gone through a lot of articles and found no solution regarding:

1. Password protecting a SQLite database using php
2. Accessing a password protected Sqlite database using PHP

Every article speaks up about encrypting the database using plugins or dlls. Can any one please tell me how to "*Password Protect*" and "*access*" Sqlite database using PHP?

Comment: Here is something about this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658880/sqlite-user-password-security

Comment: Here is a more recent posting that may solve your problem. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381264/password-protect-a-sqlite-db-is-it-possible> . If not put a reply comment and I will assist further.

Comment: Hi, I have  seen those posts earlier too. One post is for web only where they want to prevent downloading. Anotehr post shows .Net based codes. I need PHP solution.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but that's not really what SQLite is for. SQLite is built with simplicity in mind, not security. You might want to look into MySQL. I'm pretty sure the database engine itself needs plugins to even make it possible, and even then, you can only encrypt it, as opposed to just password protecting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, look into htaccess.